# MSDeploy: How to delete a single file on remote server

Tags: msdeploy

How do I delete a single file on remote server. I want to delete offline_app.htm only leaving the rest of the content in tact.

Tips appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is `-verb:delete`

```
msdeploy -verb:delete ^
         -dest:contentPath="Default Website\offline_app.htm",computer=etc
```